# Accessing Attributes of Table Cell for Functions in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following table.
[image: NEGATIVE Values]

As you can see, for some columns I have to show Average/Total in the table footer. My code works well for columns without special formatting but when there is a special formatting like we have to show NEG for negative values, in that case the calculated value is not right. So I added data-value attribute for all cell. Now I want to access the data-value attribute of each cell for the function in footerCallback.

This is html code of an example cell in table

```
<td data-value="-3.78" class="red">
    NEG
</td>
```

This is my footerCallback code.

```
"footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
                            var api = this.api(),
                                data;

                            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                            var intVal = function(i) {
                                if (typeof i === 'string') {

                                    //remove most useless characters
                                    i = i.replace(/[\$,\),\-,\%,\NEG]/g, '');

                                    //now replace ( with MIN
                                    i = i.replace('(', 'MIN');

                                    //check if i contains MIN, then remove it and multiply it with -1 to make it a negative number
                                    if (i.includes("MIN")) {
                                        i = i.replace('MIN', '');
                                        i = i * (-1);
                                    }
                                }

                                return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,\),\%,\NEG]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
                            };

                            var functionColumns = [@(string.Join(",", MathableColumns.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))))];

                            for (var i = 0; i < functionColumns.length; i++) {
                                var colIndex = functionColumns[i];

                                total = api
                                    .column(colIndex)
                                    .data()
                                    .reduce(function(a, b) {
                                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                                    }, 0);

                                total = total.toFixed(2);

                                if (total < 0)
                                {
                                    total = total * -1;
                                    $(api.column(colIndex).footer()).html(
                                        '('+total+')'
                                    );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $(api.column(colIndex).footer()).html(
                                        total
                                    );
                                }

                            }
                        },
```

I've done some research but could not find solid solution for this.

Comment: To be clear, if the value displayed is "(45)", will the data-value be "-45" or also "(45)"?

Comment: Hi @colin0117 Yes the value will be the actual value. For example (45) or NEG or (45 %) will have data-value="-45" and any positive value e.g 23 or POS or 23 % will have data-value="23".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle - http://live.datatables.net/dovirovo/1/edit, this is doing, I believe, what you want. The key part of the code is:

```
totalValues = api.column(2).nodes().toArray().map(function(node) {
  return $(node).attr('data-value');
});
```

This collects the jQuery nodes for that column, extracts the attribute, which can then be summed.

This is only doing a sum for the full column, but it should be straightforward to use this as a template to do the rows just on the current page, it just needs blending your original code and this.